# Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\

Tags: скрипт, редирект

```
<?php

         $name = "sergey";
         $pass = 123456;

       if (isset($_POST['login']))

            {

           if ($_POST['user_name']== $name  && $_POST['user_pas'])

               {header('Location: "admin/news/Forma.php"');}

             }

?>
```

переменные `$_POST` задаются в другом скрипте который обращается к этому для проверки данных. Что я тут не так сделал? 
Выдаёт ошибку

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\RBK\WWW\admin.php:2) in Z:\home\RBK\WWW\admin.php on line 17

Comment: в самом конце файла после `?>` нет лишних пробелов/переводов строк?

Comment: проверил бжыл пробел но не помогает 


Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\RBK\WWW\admin.php:2) in Z:\home\RBK\WWW\admin.php on line 13

Comment: Значит, где-то в другом месте выводятся заголовки. Или не заголовки, а просто что-то выводится. 

1) проверьте при помощи `wget -S ваш_url`, симитировав данные поста

2) не забывайте, что в Location лучше указывать [полный URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location)

Comment: спасибо проверил заработало